# Why is WCF service not invoke when security is enabled on Async operations

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

When Security feature is enabled for Authencation using X509 certificate, Connecation to the server is not established. I find this issue when the client makes Async operation call. The code below works for synchronous operation. For instance if the call is made TrainHealth instead of BeginTrainHealth, the code works fine. As I understand, security is independent of whether operations are sync or async. 
Any help on why this is not working is appreciated.

Contract :

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.bane.dk/services/fbane/2014/02/20", ConfigurationName = "Alstom.SmartBus.ESBBridge.ExternalIOPlugins.TrainData.TrainDataPort")]
public interface IStudentService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = false, Action = "TrainHealth")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    void TrainHealth(int test);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true, Action = "TrainHealth")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    System.IAsyncResult BeginTrainHealth(int test, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    void EndTrainHealth(System.IAsyncResult result);
}
```

Server Code :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost studentServiceHost = null;
            try
            {
                //Base Address for StudentService
                Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("https://10.107.64.33:5060/StudentService");

                //Instantiate ServiceHost
                studentServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StudentService), httpBaseAddress);

                CustomBinding binding = CreateBinding();
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint_GD = studentServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStudentService), binding, httpBaseAddress);

                //Add Endpoint to Host
                studentServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStudentService), binding, httpBaseAddress + "mex");

                //Metadata Exchange
                ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                serviceBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
                studentServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);
                var behavior = studentServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
                behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
                studentServiceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
                studentServiceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;

                studentServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "10.107.64.33");

                ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior newAudit = new ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior();
                newAudit.AuditLogLocation = AuditLogLocation.Application;
                newAudit.MessageAuthenticationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
                newAudit.ServiceAuthorizationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
                newAudit.SuppressAuditFailure = false;
                studentServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove<ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior>();
                studentServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(newAudit);

                studentServiceHost.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Service is live now at : {0}", httpBaseAddress);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                studentServiceHost = null;
                Console.WriteLine("There is an issue with StudentService" + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }

        public static CustomBinding CreateBinding()
        {
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
            binding.Elements.Add(new ReliableSessionBindingElement());
            TransportSecurityBindingElement sec = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
            binding.Elements.Add(sec);
            binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8));
            binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
            {
                RequireClientCertificate = true
            });

            return binding;
        }
    }
```

Client Code :

```
 class Program
    {
        static ChannelFactory<IStudentService> runTrainSvcCF = null;

        static IStudentService runTrainSvcProxy;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartClient();
        }

        private static void StartClient()
        {
            EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://10.107.64.33:5060/StudentService"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("10.107.64.34"));

            CustomBinding binding = CreateBinding();
            runTrainSvcCF = new ChannelFactory<IStudentService>(binding, endPoint);
            System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials credentials = runTrainSvcCF.Credentials;
            credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                                                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                                                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                                         "10.107.64.34");
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 0;
            credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
            runTrainSvcProxy = runTrainSvcCF.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                runTrainSvcProxy.BeginTrainHealth(88, null, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert,
                                              System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }



        public static CustomBinding CreateBinding()
        {
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
            binding.Elements.Add(new ReliableSessionBindingElement());
            binding.Elements.Add(new TransportSecurityBindingElement());
            binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8));
            binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
            {
                RequireClientCertificate = true
            });

            return binding;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Chances are the operation is failing, but you don't seem to be handling the case where the Async operation completes (allowing you to call EndTrainHealth() to check on the result of the operation).